# Remove "Call now" Call-To-Action button from a boosted (business) post

Tags: facebook-ads, facebook-business-manager, meta-business-suite

I made a post with a picture and boosted it (to show as an Ad) with Facebook.

I have naively accepted the suggestion to include a "Call Now" button in it. It is terrible because it disables loading the attached picture. By clicking on the picture, it wants to call instead of showing the informative picture.

The worst of it all is that it is impossible to turn off this button. I have tried numerous options of editing the post, the ad, the campaign, I have even stopped the campaign, and nothing helped.

If anyone could help me by turning this off, it would be greatly appreciated. If not, still it would be useful for anyone to know that they shouldn't use this feature, because it is unstoppable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me as well. I was able to fix this by following these steps:

1. Remove ad(s) from the post.
2. Edit the post.
3. Remove the photo.
4. Edit the post again to re-upload the photo.

This removed the call now action for me!